# Is it ok to use deprecated themes for TimePicker

Tags: android

So some users doesn't like the Material Time Picker theme and would like the old (deprecated) theme
but I was wondering if it was 'ok' to use it. I understand deprecated methods are dangerous but is it the same thing for a Theme ?

I need to use the deprecated AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT instead of the Material alternative

Answer (score 0):

While `deprecated` means "this is going to be removed, so better do not touch" it will still work unless it stop in future due to i.e. being completely removed. So it is not advised to use any deprecated elements in newly written code because that is just creating pure [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) which you will have to pay off in the future. You better look how to achieve your goal without touching tainted features to save yourself from the need of future refactoring.

Comment: Yeah, I understand technical debt, I do hope that some themes will stick in the future. For this purpose only, it's just a small part of the code so i think I'll go for it while still looking to customize the theme to be Material-like. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use deprecated methods as long as the depreciated method exists.

Deprecated method means that there is a better way is available to do that particular task. Deprecated method might be removed in future version.

Comment: Deprecated methods are kinda dangerous to use unlike a theme (unless the theme is your app theme). Thanks for the answer